# Help with $\frac12 \log_2 x - \frac1{\log_2 x} = \frac76$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am supposed to get $x = 8$ and $x = x^{-2/3}$. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: $\frac 1 {\log x}$ is not generally the same as $\log \frac 1 x $

Comment: Did you mean $x=\mathbf 2^{-2/3}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE, and thanks for providing your own thoughts on the problem. But next time use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as required. It's not only much neater than handwriting, it's searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\left( \log_2(x) \right)^{-1} \neq \log_2 \left(x^{-1} \right)$$

For example, take $x = 4$. Then

$$\left( \log_2(x) \right)^{-1} = \left( \log_2(4) \right)^{-1} = 2^{-1} = \frac 1 2$$

but

$$\log_2 \left(x^{-1} \right) = \log_2 \left( \frac 1 4 \right) = -2$$

This is where your error lies.

Answer (score 3):

To get the correct answer, let $L=\log_2(x).$

Then we have $$\frac 1  2 L - \frac 1 L = \frac 7 6.$$

Multiply by $6L$ to get $$3L^2-6=7L.$$

Thus $$3L^2-7L-6=0$$

or $$(3L+2)(L-3)=0.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Not gonna lie, that's a pretty slick solution (even if it's just a minor trick involving a substitution - I always love it when something like that makes the work look 10 times easier :p).

Comment: I know how to solve in this way, I was just confused about why I got a different answer when using another approach. But still thank you for your help ;)